# Why the outputs of "freebsd-version" and "freebsd-version -k" are different?

Tags: freebsd

I am a novice of `FreeBSD`, and follow this [document](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/10.3R/installation.html) to upgrade from `10.2` to `10.3`. But after rebooting, I find "`freebsd-version`" and "`freebsd-version -k`" output different:

```
# freebsd-version
10.3-RELEASE-p5
# freebsd-version -k
10.3-RELEASE-p4
```

After referring [freebsd-version](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=freebsd-version&sektion=1) document:

> -k      Print the version and patch level of the installed kernel.
>            Unlike uname(1), if a new kernel has been installed but the
>            system has not yet rebooted, freebsd-version will print the
>            version and patch level of the new kernel.

I still can't figure out why the outputs of "`freebsd-version`" and "`freebsd-version -k`" are different. Could anyone help to explain the cause?

Comment: Can't tell you myself because I don't know enough about this, but it looks like the answers [in this post](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/47972/#post-267882) and the next three or four may help you figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`freebsd-version -ku` will give you the version and patch level of the kernel and userland respectively.

Many of the updates apply to both the kernel and userland, in which case the patch level of both components increment together. However, occasionally, only the userland requires a patch, in which case the kernel patch level remains unchanged.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! Is there any case the userland version lags behind kernel version?

Comment: I think that it is unlikely, but I do not know if it is impossible.